# Some elements are just magically not removed from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, try-catch, game-engine

ok here's the block of code i wrote :

```
public ArrayList<Location> possibleMoves() {
   ArrayList<Location> a1 = new ArrayList<Location>(); // an array to contain all       possible locations
   Board testB = new Board(); // a test board to test if locations are valid or not
   // locations have x & y coordinates 
          a1.add(new Location(getCurrentLocation().getx() - 1,                    getCurrentLocation().gety() + 1));
          a1.add(new Location(getCurrentLocation().getx() + 1, getCurrentLocation().gety() - 1));
          a1.add(new Location(getCurrentLocation().getx() - 1, getCurrentLocation().gety() - 1));
          a1.add(new Location(getCurrentLocation().getx() + 1, getCurrentLocation().gety() + 1));
          for (int i = 0; i < a1.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    Tower testTower = testB.getGrid()[a1.get(i).getx()][a1.get(i).gety()];
                }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    a1.remove(a1.get(i));
                } 
         }
         return a1;
      }
```

Comment: When you remove an element from the list, the size decrease, so you might not go over all the elements of it.

Comment: Well i am passing to the method remove an element and not an index so what now ?

Comment: What I'm saying is that if an element is removed (either if you use `remove(Object o)` or `remove(int index)`), you decrease the size by one. If you take a look at this example, you would expect that all the elements of the list are removed but that's not the case. http://ideone.com/lenN8O

Answer (score 1):

When you remove the element, the position of the following ones is decreased. Do this also to `i`. And, you can just use `remove(int)`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a1.size(); i++) {
    try {
        Tower testTower = testB.getGrid()[a1.get(i).getx()][a1.get(i).gety()];
    } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        a1.remove(i--);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove elements from a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) while visiting its elements I suggest to used the following pattern:

```
Iterator<Location> locationsIt = a1.iterator();
while (locationsIt.hasNext()) {
  Location location = locationsIt.next();
  try {
    Tower testTower = testB.getGrid()[location.getx()][location.gety()];
  } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    locationsIt.remove();
  }
}
```

It's easy to use and it's not error prone.